# Status code:413 - File greater than 1 MB not uploaded on iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, nginx, file-upload, ios10

I have implemented code for `nginx` upload file to server using `NSURLSession` for speed test. This is working properly on `iOS 8` but on `iOS 10` it is giving status code `413` (request entity too large).

File size is approx `30MB`, If file size is less then `1MB` it's working properly. Here is my code

```
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

NSString* FileParamConstant = @"file";
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kPathForUploadCheck];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:600];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“myfile” ofType:@"psd"];    
NSData   *imageData22      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString *base64String = [imageData22 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSData *imageData = [base64String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setURL:requestURL];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *backgroundSeesion = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURL* tempUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
uploadTask = [backgroundSeesion uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:tempUrl];
uploadTask = [backgroundSeesion uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Any error you get ?

Comment: it gives  status code 413(request entity too large) and return task completed in response 2-3 seconds but file not uploaded  on server.

Comment: Give details about the error as well.

Comment: Error is nil in didCompleteWithErrorwhen and when I print task.response

{ URL: http://myserver.com/speedTest/fileUpload.php } { status code: 413, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 199;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Mar 2017 09:53:25 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.2";
} }

Comment: use FTP sever to upload large size file

Comment: can you put the code how we can use FTP server? how I can get upload speed?

Comment: Pleae go through below link : https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=FTP+class+ios+%2B+github&*